# Apple script - formatted text to strikethrough but how do I also change its colour? - In Notes

Tags: applescript, automator

I have an Automator Quick Action routine that changes the font of selected text to Strikethrough.  Is it possible to also change the colour of the selected text to Blue please?

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Notes" to activate

    tell application "System Events"
        click menu item "Strikethrough" of menu of menu item "Font" of menu "Format" of menu bar 1 of application process "Notes" of application "System Events"
    end tell

return input
end run
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automate changing the *color* of *selected text* in **Notes** it can be done with **UI Scripting**, which you are already using to click **Strikethrough** on the *menu*.

Since you did not specify a *color* or which *tab* on the **Colors** *window* you want to work with, I'll show two examples, one for the **Pencils** *tab* and the other for the **Color Palettes** *tab*.

With the *text* already *selected* in **Notes**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me in **macOS Catalina**, using **US English** for the **Language**:

For the **Pencils** *tab*:

```
tell application "Notes" to activate

delay 0.25

tell application "System Events"

    --  # Click the Strikethrough menu.

    click menu item "Strikethrough" of ¬
        menu "Font" of ¬
        menu item "Font" of ¬
        menu "Format" of ¬
        menu bar item "Format" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Notes"

    --  # Show the Colors window, if not visible.

    if not (exists window "Colors" of application process "Notes") then
        keystroke "c" using {shift down, command down}
        repeat until (exists window "Colors" of application process "Notes")
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
    end if

    --  # Change the color of the selected text.

    tell application process "Notes"
        tell window "Colors"
            --  # Click the Pencils tab.
            click (every button of toolbar 1 whose description is "Pencils")
            --  # 
            --  # Valid colors for the Pencils tab are:
            --  # 
            --  # "Licorice", "Lead", "Tungsten", "Iron", "Steel", "Tin", "Nickel", "Aluminum", "Magnesium", "Silver", "Mercury", "Snow",
            --  # "Cayenne", "Mocha", "Asparagus", "Fern", "Clover", "Moss", "Teal", "Ocean", Midnight", "Eggplant", "Plum", "Maroon", 
            --  # "Maraschino", "Tangerine", "Lemon", "Lime", "Spring", "Sea Foam", "Turquoise", "Aqua", "Blueberry", "Grape", "Magenta", "Strawberry",
            --  # "Salmon", "Cantaloupe", "Banana", "Honeydew", "Flora", "Spindrift", "Ice", "Sky", "Orchid", "Lavender", "Bubblegum", "Carnation"
            --  # 
            set myColor to "Tangerine"
            click (every radio button of ¬
                radio group 1 of ¬
                splitter group 1 whose description is myColor)
            click button 1 --   # Close the Colors window.          
        end tell
    end tell

end tell
```

---

For the **Color Palettes** *tab*, use the following *block* of *example* **AppleScript** *code* in place of the same `tell application process "Notes"` *block* of *code* in the *code* shown above:

```
--  # Change the color of the selected text.

tell application process "Notes"
    tell window "Colors"
        --  # Click the Color Palettes tab.
        click (every button of toolbar 1 whose description is "Color Palettes")
        --  #       
        --  # Valid colors for the Color Palettes tab are:
        --  # 
        --  # "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cyan", "Green", "Magenta", "Orange", "Purple", "Red", "Yellow", "White"
        --  # 
        set myColor to "Red"
        try
            select (every row of ¬
                table 1 of ¬
                scroll area 1 of ¬
                splitter group 1 ¬
                    whose value of text field 1 is myColor)
        end try
        click button 1 --   # Close the Colors window.          
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and, sans the included `try` *statement* in the *code* for the **Color Palettes** *tab*, does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In Notes, under the format menu, there is a font menu item and under this is an option to show colors. Opening this and clicking on a color will change the font to the selected color.

So a direct method isn't there. If the complexity is worth it:

- use `cliclick`. Brew has it.
- Find out the coordinates of the color you want to use, using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

Add this part in the automator:

- Using automator, activate the color panel. Format menu > Font > show colors.
- Emulate a click on the coordinates using `cliclick` using "do shell script"

Comment: I think they want it in automator, not via GUI

Comment: you are right but it sounded to me like OP wasn't aware of how to change the font color so I used that as my answer. Once he knows how to do it OP can write the script.  But if you think I should delete my answer i will. just say the word.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh I didnt downvote it. Since the color button isn't in the menus, I don't think automator action is possible easily. .

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm not really bothered if it runs in Automator or as a stand alone script but need help with the actual scripting.  It seems to me that the colour menu doesn't always appear in the same place, so not sure how the GUI will work?

Comment: @ankii, While `cliclick` is a nice _utility_, it's not well suited for what the OP wants to do, as it is much easier to use **UI Scripting** in the use case. There would be a considerable amount of _coding_ to get `cliclick` to do the same thing I did with **UI Scripting** in the answer I posted.

Comment: @Niscors It opens for me in the same place, even after quitting. Maybe you should _set it_ to some location manually & see if it changes its place or not.

Comment: @user3439894 yeah well, it's _Jugaad_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugaad

Comment: @user3439894, this is just the job thanks very much.  I just changed the spelling of Color to the proper UK version (LOL) and it works fine on my UK system.